# Adding button to listview group header

Tags: c#, listview

I have C# ListView with groups that are collapsible [from codeproject.com](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36775/Collapsible-ListViewGroup)

now I would like to have click event triggered on group header click. I've read that this is not possible but that some kind of link can be added to group header?

I need to get KEY (id) of clicked group.

If this is even possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ObjectListView](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net) adds lots of abilities to a standard ListView, including events when a `ListViewGroup` is clicked or expanded. Even if you don't want to use it, you can look at the code to see how it is done (it's a little complicated).

[This blog](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/blog5.html) describes what was need to add hit tests et al for `ListViewGroups`.

`ObjectListView` also has the ability to add a clickable link into the group header ([this recipe shows how](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/recipes.html#how-do-i-use-that-little-clicky-thing-next-to-a-group-header)). For example "Check bank balace" and "Open calendar" in this screenshot:

[image: Groups with clickable links]